# User unable to access files in a folder with SUID S bit set

Tags: file-permissions, chmod

I have a folder which I want to share with users of a group named `frx`. I had applied `chmod g+s` to the folder, but for some reason the SUID bit (for folders in the /home/frx directory) came out as `S` instead.

```
> pwd
/home/frx

> ls -al
drwxrws---+  14 ferc frx    4096 Dec 24 23:20 .
drwxr-xr-x    8 root root   4096 Dec  2 12:48 ..
... 
drwxrwS---+  20 pi   frx    4096 Dec 19 18:50 views
```

From what I read, `s` and `S` shouldn't be any different if a user is just opening a file. However, another user in the group `frx` is unable to view or access files in the `views` directory, even though there are read/write permissions for the group. (He could `touch` files in /home/frx without problem.) Why is this happening?

How do I change the SUID bit to `s` for a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access files in a directory, the user must be granted execute permission on that directory.

`S` (uppercase `s`) indicates that the sticky bit is set for a group but execute bit - is not. And this is why another user from `frx` group cannot access any files in the `views` directory. You must set both group sticky and execute bits for this to work properly.

Comment: This is new to me. Wonder under what scenarios would a directory require `rw` but not `x`?

Comment: `r` alone allows directory listing. I am not sure if `w` alone would work (I can imagine it allows hardlinking to existing file). `x` alone allows opening a file in a directory if you know its exact name, `wx` would also allow creating a file.

Comment: I had `rwS` for the group, and a group member couldn't see the directory listing. It was just ????????. Couldn't read a file. Couldn't overwrite a file either.

Comment: Yes, it was just that.